# Getevent and pointer location

Tags: android, touch, adb

I am trying to get the (x, y) coordinate of the touch through the pointer location option in Developer Options and I use these coordinates to tap on the screen using sendevent. Here is my script that does the sendevent.

tap.sh

`sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 57 2421
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 58 232
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 53 $1
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 54 $2
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 57 4294967295
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0`

I call the script from adb shell `sh tap.sh <x> <y>` but it is not tapping on the right coordinate. Instead it is tapping at a different location.

Also when I tap on the screen and check the result in getevent `adb shell getevent`. I find that the coordinates that is shown on the pointer location and the getevent are different.

Why are they different and how do I solve this issue?

PS: The devices I tried are Nexus 7, Nexus 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28217144/1778421

Answer (score 6):

The X and Y co-ordinates obtained from the [getevent](https://source.android.com/devices/input/getevent.html) and the ones obtained from the pointer location in developer options are not the same. They are mapped using a formula.

```
displayX = (x - minX) * displayWidth / (maxX - minX + 1)
displayY = (y - minY) * displayHeight / (maxY - minY + 1)
```

Source: [Touch Devices](https://source.android.com/devices/input/touch-devices)

Comment: Do you have any idea, How to get Screen_X and Screen_Y using "adb shell dumpsys input" in latest android version (Q OS , Security patch > feb 2020)?

Comment: You can get your displayHeight/Width with dumpsys and min/max x/y values with "adb shell -- getevent -lp /dev/input/eventXXX". Just add your specific event id.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on developer options and enable `Pointer Location` and you can see the x and y coordinates on top of the screen when you tap on the screen use those coordinates to send tap events.

Comment: can i get these x,y in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that getevent (in my experience, this possibly varies between devices) shows base 16 values?

(side note: `getevent -l` is often easier to read as it prints a string representation of the event types)

i.e. if `getevent -l` says

```
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cb       
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000376
```

the position of the touch is `(459, 886)` actually

however it appears that sendevent is not following suit in requiring hex values if your code works at all, as your (such as) `53` and `54` work where I would have used
`0035` and `0036`.

Edit:

Having tried the original code on a Nexus 5 (correct device file substituted in), I have found that no touch event is generated (nor when the hexadecimal equivalent is substituted, for experimental rigor), nor from reusing values captured (and converted) from `getevent`. Previously, I have had better experience converting the events with a Python script based on the C one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063057/android-simulate-fast-swipe), and writing the output directly to the device file.

Edit 2:

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501397/nexus-one-ignores-touch-events-sent-via-adb?rq=1) suggests that the initial code should work.