# How to get touch screen resolution via ADB

Tags: android, adb

There is a touch screen layer overlapping the display layer of the Android device, and I remember reading a post on SO providing the command to get the touch screen resolution, but I don't seem to be able to find that post. Does any one know the adb command to shell into the device and get the resolution for the touch screen? Thanks.

```
       _____________
   ___/            /      
  /  /            /
 /  /____________/ <- touch screen
/__________/ <- display screen
```

Comment: Are you thinking `adb shell dumpsys input`? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys

Comment: Yeah, likely, probably in somewhere in `std` of `adb -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys input`

Comment: Perhaps ['Input Reader State'](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys#reader_state)

Comment: From a quick glance, I don't see meta data indicating the resolution itself, but it could still be there. This is meta data about a kernel report being provided to the touch screen driver, and I do see the coordinates of the touch event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28217144/1778421

Comment: Yep, looks like that was the post.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, as per the title of the candidate duplicate.